# Use DropDownList in IE 11 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I am having a problem to use **DropDownList** in IE 11.

When select value in **DropDownList** the event **OnSelectedIndexChanged** not firing.

**I can't update the framework version from 4 to 4.5.**

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

My code below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="theDates" runat="server" CssClass="ddl_Class" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="theDates_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="[Selected value]" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="-------------------------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


    protected void theDates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }

 <select name="theDates" id="theDates" class="ddl_Class">
    <option selected="selected" value="">[Selected value]</option>
    <option value="">-------------------------</option>
    <option value="01/01/2015 00:00:00">01/01/2015</option>
    <option value="02/01/2015 00:00:00">02/01/2015</option>
    <option value="04/01/2015 00:00:00">04/01/2015</option>
    <option value="05/01/2015 00:00:00">05/01/2015</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT #1**

```
private void BindData()
{
    gvProducts.DataSource = RetrieveProducts();
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}


private DataSet RetrieveProducts()
{
    if (user == true)
    {
        string sql = "...";

        DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

        using (OdbcConnection cn =
          new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
            {

                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dsProducts);

            }
        }

        return dsProducts;
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('Ended user.');", true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know its IE11 problem? had you tried running in compatibility mode?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: thank you for reply; on the IE 11 version I can't modify compatibility mode because is blocked for administrator.

Comment: do you use any update panel?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch no update panel on the aspx markup

Answer (score 0):

If you run ASP.NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003, you will have problems with both Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11. This is because ASP.NET fails to detect those versions of Internet Explorer.

http://rikter.com/articles/2013/12/internet-explorer-11-and-asp-net/